# Can I crack a zip file using Hash Suite on Windows?

Tags: hash, passwords, md5

I'm trying to crack a password I set on a zip file using Hash Suite but it doesn't seem to work for me (not sure if I'm doing everything correctly).

Basically, this is what I've done:

1. Created a text file, compressed it to a zip file with WinRar and set a password to it (pw: 123).
2. Opened Hash Suite -> Hash Calculator -> Hash a file, and I chose the zip file. The program now displays the hash in MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA-2 256, SHA-2 512.
3. I save the MD5 hash in a text file, then import the text file into Hash Suite.
4. Lastly, I choose to start an attack in RAW-MD5 and the program runs for 1 minute.

I get not results whatsoever. Anyone knows the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've calculated the MD5 *of the file itself*, not of its password ('123').

According to [its download page](https://hashsuite.openwall.net/download), the only hashes supported by Hash Suite are as follows (and ZIP files are not included):

```
LM, NTLM, Raw-MD5, Raw-SHA1, Raw-SHA256, Raw-SHA512, 
DCC, DCC2, SSHA, MD5CRYPT, BCRYPT, WPA-PSK
```

Compressed file formats are only supported for storing wordlists, not for attacking the hashes for those formats.

You can't crack a ZIP file with Hash Suite. (But you *can* crack some of them with its cousin, [John the Ripper](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper).)